# Auto-submit form javascript sending error to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I ended up using the following script in order to auto-submit forms to my server after 60 seconds. However, for some reason the forms are reporting an error.

```
</style>
<script> 
  var counter{{num}} = {{seconds}};
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter{{num}}--;
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
  document.getElementById("counter{{num}}").innerHTML = "Timer:"+counter{{num}}
    if (counter{{num}} == 0) {
    // Submit form  
    test.submit('timeout');
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
<p id="counter{{num}}" style="text-align: right;">COUNTER</p>
```

The script looks a little funny because there is this `{{num}}' value. This is basically replaced by a different number using server side scripting each time the form is called so that multiple functions are not generated simultaneously which force the timer to zero twice or three times faster than before.

Sorry if this is unclear. I tried every solution to auto-submit this form but I think there were server side conflicts with my javascript. This is all pretty new to me.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: `test.submit('timeout');` here what us test?

Comment: If `test` is a form - form's `submit` does not expect any parameters.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how this is defined but I think `test` is a special class or object type used by the server software. It takes a single value which is typically the name of whatever button submitted the form. I don't think this is the source of error but I might be mistaken.

Comment: FYI: using setInterval and subtracting a variable for a countdown is not accurate.

Comment: What is `test`? Where is it defined?